# Adding all Case Contacts to the 'Send an email' action

Tags: quickaction

I am using an action on the case object:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Az5.png]

We also have the Case contact roles, related list on the case.

I want that when clicking on the 'Send an email' button, all the related contacts, will be added to the 'To recipients' field.

The field is populated such:
[image]

But this is not the whole list, just related contacts on the case.

Can I do that from the Action button ?